# Uncheck selected checkbox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I've a `checkbox` which defined as below:

```
<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox x:Name="CampaignCb" Tag="{Binding Campaign}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Checked="CampaignCb_Checked" Unchecked="CampaignCb_Unchecked" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

How can I unchecked the selected `checkbox` programmatically? I've try with `CampaignCb.IsChecked = false` but it doesn't work for my case since my checkbox is bound to a source.

**Edit:**
Here's how I populate the data into the list view:

```
CampaignTabLv.Items.Add(new 
{ 
  Campaign = OutboundConfig.campName[i], Status = OutboundConfig.campStatus[i].ToString(), 
  Mode = OutboundConfig.campDialMode[i].ToString(), Description = OutboundConfig.campDesc[i], 
  CampaignID = OutboundConfig.campID[i], GroupID = OutboundConfig.campGroupID[i], 
  OptimizeGoal = OutboundConfig.campOptimizeGoal[i], OptimizationMethod =   OutboundConfig.campOptimizationMethod[i].ToString() 
});
```

And this is how I can the value from my selection when the `checkbox` is checked:

```
private void CampaignCb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var selectedCampaign = (dynamic)CampaignTabLv.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

Comment: We need to see your view and viewmodel.

Comment: You bound `IsChecked` to a ListView. What's the purpose?

Comment: @nobodykid, the number of item in the listview depends on the how many item in the source

Comment: @YWah when do(at what event) do you want to uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: As your `CheckBox` is bound, why don't you just unselect the `ListViewItem` it is bound to?

Comment: @YWah let me guess. if this runs, there will be a list of checkbox, and the checked one is determined by the binding. is it correct?

Comment: @nobodykid, yes, you are right